# SQL Server Update on Table A if record not found in table b

Tags: sql-server

Having following Table:

Table Name `PLANS`

Field Names

```
Key  EMP _ID
Key  PLAN_NUMBER
STATUS
FIELD1
FIELD2
FIELD3
FIELD4
```

Table Name `PLANS_TEMP`

```
Key  EMP_ID
Key  PLAN_NUMBER
STATUS
FIELD1
FIELD2
FIELD3
FIELD4
```

Wants to have data of `PLANS_TEMP` in `PLANS` table.

Don’t want to delete record instead wants to set status = ‘I’ if records doesn’t exists in `PLANS_TEMP`

1. If record doesn’t exists in Office_Plan_temp Wants to update Office_Plan.Status = ‘I’

Something like following:

```
Update P
Set status = ‘I’
Where emp_id and plan_number not exists in Plans_Temp table
```

(We have to match LOCATION_ID &  PLAN_NUMBER)

2. If Record found in Plans_Temp table but not in Plans table, wants to insert.
3. For all the existing records, wants to check if there’s any change in field1, field2, field3 and field4 then update.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need `MERGE` in this situation. More info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may help you:

```
MERGE PLANS as target
USING PLANS_TEMP as source
ON target.EMP_ID = source.EMP_ID AND target.PLAN_NUMBER = source.PLAN_NUMBER
--If record doesn’t exists in Office_Plan_temp Wants to update Office_Plan.Status = ‘I’
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    UPDATE SET [STATUS] = 'I'
--If Record found in Plans_Temp table but not in Plans table, wants to insert.
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (EMP_ID, PLAN_NUMBER, [STATUS], FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4)
    VALUES (source.EMP_ID, source.PLAN_NUMBER, source.[STATUS], source.FIELD1, source.FIELD2, source.FIELD3, source.FIELD4)
--For all the existing records, (! HERE UPDATE WITHOUT ANY CHECKING wants to check if there’s any change in) field1, field2, field3 and field4 then update.
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET  target.FIELD1 = source.FIELD1,
                target.FIELD2 = source.FIELD2,
                target.FIELD3 = source.FIELD2,
                target.FIELD4 = source.FIELD4;
```